# python-xarray: open_mfdataset in which one .nc file has no populated time axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, netcdf, netcdf4, python-xarray

I am attempting to open a series of netcdf4 datasets. using something like:

```
import xarray as xr; import os; import fnmatch
def new_arr(string):
    return xr.open_mfdataset([ f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if fnmatch.fnmatch(f,string) == True])
```

The boolean provides me with a list of files matching what I want to load into the dataset. This works so long as all matching files in the directory have at least one entry in the (unlimited) time axis. However, if one file does not, xarray decides to just throw me an error.

Is there a concise pythonic way to have xarray pass over matching files that have time axes of length zero and still give me the dataset or am I going to be forced to run a bash script to get rid of the exceptions beforehand?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is:
   `IndexError: The indexing operation you are attempting to perform is not valid on netCDF4.Variable object. Try loading your data into memory first by calling .load().`


`Original traceback:`

`Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    array = getitem(self.get_array(), key.tuple)

File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 3961, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 4796, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable._get
IndexError`

Comment: Is this the exact line it is breaking on?  I have not been able to recreate this error.